# What happens when we use document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]?

Tags: javascript

What is the process happening in Browser when we use `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`. I have the below code to be executed. What is the difference in the flow when we use `<script type="javascript" src=""myJs.js"></script>` somewhere in the `<body> or <head>` with the below one.

```
function addJavascript(jsname,pos) {
var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
s.setAttribute('src',jsname);
th.appendChild(s);
}
addJavascript("myJs.js","body");
```

I also want to know what happens when we use `document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What in the descriptions (for example in the MDN) of the functions do you want explained ?

Comment: My intention is to know what document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0] does.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("tag here")[0]
```

**This will find the first element in the html with the tag specified**

In case of body and head tag, it is not doing anything special as they are defined only once.

Comment: I have a piece of JavaScript code which will be invoked asynchronously while the <body> is being rendered. It is unpredictable that when this code will be inserted to page. Also, I have a JavaScript file which will be loaded in the page and which will process the JavaScript piece of code. I am unable to change the code in the JS file. Also, I am unable to directly place the JavaScript code somewhere in the page. The code will be inserted from an external tool to the page.

Comment: Now, the JavaScript file contains document.write method to create an image. But, this method is not recommended since it is impossible to predict when the write action will take place. For example, if the code snippet runs after the body rendering finishes and after the DOM is loaded, the page content will be entirely rewritten.

I want to make sure that the above worst situation should not take place.

Answer (score 1):

I'm uncertain whats actually asked here, so I guess you're confused about the `[0]` part.

Well, `document.getElementsByTagName` queries for an unknown number of elements within your markup. It will return a `HTMLCollection`, which is an *Array-like* structure. Thats why we need to address specific elements within that list via brackets.

`<body>` and `<head>` elements are only allowed onced within a valid HTML document, so this might look a little confusing. A better way to get those nodes is directly, via reference:

```
var head = document.head,
    body = document.body;
```

To be on the save side, combine that with a fallback and you're fine

```
head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
```

Comment: Please find my comment in the above answer

Answer (score 0):

From your comment on the question:

> My intention is to know what document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0] does.

`document.getElementsByTagName` finds the elements that exist in the document *as of when you call it* that have that tag (`body`, `head`, `p`, `a`, `div`, etc.) So since you're calling it with the tag name `"body"`, it finds all `body` elements in the document, if there are any when you call it.

`[0]` then tries to get the first entry from the resulting list. If the list is empty, you get back `undefined`.

So `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` either gives you the first (and presumably only) `body` element in the document, or `undefined` if there is none (yet).

> What is the difference in the flow when we use `<script type="javascript" src=""myJs.js"></script>` somewhere in the `<body>` or `<head>` with the below one.

Well, if you have it in the `<head>` and you run it looking for the `body` tag, `document.getElementsByTagName('body')` will return an empty node list (since the `head` **must** precede the `body`), and so `[0]` on that will give you `undefined`, and attempts to use `appendChild` on it will fail.

---

If you just want to reliably add a `script` element on the page, from a script, the usual thing is to use:

```
var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].parentNode;
// ...create your new script element
parent.appendChild(yourScript);
```

...since if your script is running (and you didn't defer it and remove the script element that included it), you know there's at least one `script` element *somewhere* on the page.

Comment: Please find my comment in the first answer

Comment: @RaheebM: That has nothing to do with the question you actually asked, and then reconfirmed when Dystroy asked you what you were actually asking. If you want to know how to reliably append content to a page without using `document.write`, ask that question instead. *This* question has been answered (by multiple people).